# Lasso Application in SAS

Tags: cross-validation, lasso, sas

I have a question regarding the Lassoapplication in SAS using cross validation method (choose =cvex and stop=none). I test different regression models and very often Lasso keeps all the variables such that all of them stay in the model. So I thought, when there is no penalty, that all coefficients should be equal to the OLS solution. This is most time the case but sometimes the coefficients are different from the OLS regression. Because I chose the option stop=none, all steps are shown by SAS and so I thought that the last step is the step without penalty. Does someone have an idea why this is the case. The code is the following:

```
proc glmselect data=mylib.test plots=all seed=123; 
where 1998<= year <=2002; 
model y= x1 ... x12 /selection=LASSO (stop=none choose=cvex); 
run;
```

Thank you very much for an answer.